# How can I programmatically extract type information from a Python project using Pylance?

Tags: python, types, mypy, pylance, pyright

I'm working on a project where I need to analyze a Python codebase and extract type information for specific variables programatically. I'm interested in using Pylance (or the underlying Pyright) since I've found its type inference to be quite accurate when using it with VS Code.

Is there a way to programmatically use Pylance or Pyright to analyze Python code and retrieve type information?

What I've considered so far:

Language Server Protocol (LSP):
Pylance operates as a language server using the Language Server Protocol (LSP). I thought about setting up an LSP client, starting the Pylance language server, and then sending LSP requests to get type information. However, I'm unsure about the specifics of this approach.

Using Pyright Directly:
Since Pyright is the core type-checker behind Pylance, I considered using it directly as a library to analyze the code. But I'm not sure about the internal APIs and how to leverage them for this purpose programatically.

Alternative Tools:
I know there are other tools like mypy that might offer programmatic APIs for analyzing Python code. But I'm particularly interested in Pylance/Pyright due to their accuracy in type inference.

Manual Parsing:
As a last resort, I thought about manually parsing the Python code using the ast library to extract type hints. This wouldn't provide inferred types, but it might be a starting point.

A simple example:

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self, name: str, age: int):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
        
    def get_age(self) -> int:
        return self.age

def add_numbers(a: int, b: int) -> int:
    return a + b

def main():
    # Create a Person object
    person = Person("Alice", 30)
    
    # Invoke get_age method and print the result
    age = person.get_age()
    print(f"{person.name}'s age is {age} years old.")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

For the line "age = person.get_age()", for person variable, I want to know that it of type "Person". I have to do this programmatically.

Has anyone attempted something similar or have insights on how to achieve this? Any guidance or pointers would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What do you mean by "retrieve type information"? Exactly what kinds of variables/functions/parameters/arguments do you need type information on? Can you include a sample piece of source code and the output you expect from your desired tool checking against this code?

Comment: A sample example added @blhsing

Comment: I'd use a pylance LS running in the background, there's probably 10 different libraries to interact with a language server on python. Shouldn't be too difficult to do, this is what vscode does as well

Comment: @0x150 can you please point me to any code in gist or related reference? : pray: